# html5 audio and supporting Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i have written some simple html and javascript that should play a sound file.  The page displays the two buttons but when i click the play button it does nothing .  I know that my browser can play my mp3 file because it works with just the audio tag ex:

```
<audio src="soundtest.mp3" ></audio>
```

If anyone could tell me what i am doing wrong i would greatly appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="playSong()" type="button">play</button>
<button onclick="pauseSong()" type="button">pause</button>
<br>

<audio id="audio1">
<source src="soundtest.mp3" type="audio/mp3" >
  Your browser does not support the audio tag!
</audio>

<script> 
var mySong=document.getElementById("audio1"); 

function playSong()
  { 
  mySong.play();

  } 

function pauseSong()
  { 
  mySong.pause();

  } 


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the browser say? please define "not playing"

Comment: I would try type="audio/mpeg"

Comment: that was it akonsu thanks!!! I have another issue it seems to work on my safari but not my firefox 17.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to try. First and foremost, check `mySong.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")`. It should return "maybe". If it does not, your browser doesn't support MP3 and you should try a different one.

Then, the `<audio>` tag's `type` attribute should be `audio/mpeg`, not `audio/mp3`. MIME type is important.

So important, in fact, that if it still doesn't work you should check to ensure that the server is configured to serve `.mp3` files with the `audio/mpeg` MIME type header.

If this still doesn't work... try turning the speakers on :p I'm kidding, if you still have problems after these steps, let me know.

Comment: akonsu told me the same thing about the audio/mpeg...and that was the issue.  It works fine now on safari...but for some reason it wont work on firefox 17.0.1

Comment: also how would i play multiple songs in a row.  ex. clicking the play button and playing multiple songs until the user clicks pause...

Comment: Firefox does not support MP3. I cannot fathom the logic in not supporting the single most commonly used file format for sounds... Anyway, if you want a playlist, it's quite involved and you should probably Google some tutorials.